# maxlength conflicting with webkit

Tags: html, css

I added a `maxlength` setting to my number input and it worked until I tried to remove the number arrows from the side. Do they somehow conflict with eachother?

```html
<input type='number' id='numberInput' maxlength='16' placeholder='Enter a number*'></input>
```

It stopped working when I added this to the css

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     text-align: center;
}
 :-moz-placeholder {
     text-align: center;
     -moz-appearance: text-field;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5zbjLd9/) (commented) for inspection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxlength` is not supported by `type="number"`. It would work if you switch to `type="text"`, but on mobile devices you will lose the numerical keyboard as first suggestion.

As workaround, try to replace `maxlenght="16"` with `onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==16) return false;"`,